# Python compare differences - part 2

Tags: python

I have asked a similar question like this before but I am going to try again because I have some more questions.

I have two csv files that have 3 columns.

Name    Product    Amount:

I want to get the differences between the two files. I can do this if the two files are in the same order of name and product. This will give me the differences of amount which is what I am looking for.

I am needing to have something that will take to list and compare the two and show differences if not in same order.

I have tried:

```
import csv
import difflib 


file1 = open('file1','rb').read().splitlines()
file2 = open('file1','rb').read().splitlines()

for diff in difflib.ndiff(file1, file2):
    print(diff)
```

But if any thing is out of order no good. Is there a way I can group each "name product amount" and compare to file 2 where I have grouped each "name product amount", and if there is a difference between file 1 and file 2 show that.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can loop directly over a file - no need to do ``read().splitlines()`` (which would be better simplified to ``.readlines()`` if you needed a list anyway). Also, it might be worth using a context manager ([the ``with`` statement](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example)) where opening files.

Comment: @Lattyware: `difflib.ndiff` (at least in 2.7) requires lists of strings, not files or iterators over strings, so he does need the list. Unless, of course, he can use a different function. But you're right that `readlines()` is still better than `read().splitlines()`.

Comment: @abarnert This is true, I'd recommend simply ``readlines()`` as you say then.

Comment: @Lattyware: Well, I agree with your agreement with my agreement with your recommendation. :) Anyway, the 2.7 docs' examples show `fromlines = open(fromfile, 'U').readlines()`, while the 3.3 version shows `with open(fromlines) as fromf, open(tofile) as tof:
        fromlines, tolines = list(fromf), list(tof)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the lines using the python builtin function `sorted(alist)` or sort them inplace, using `alist.sort()`.

Also, you can use the UNIX command `sort` on the files before you open them in python. That way you can be sure they are both in order.

Comment: Of course he could also use the command `diff` on the result of calling `sort`, before opening anything in Python…

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need `difflib` in the first place?

First, you only want the minimal diff lines, not any context, etc., so a fancy diff algorithm is a bit of overkill.

And presumably you're going to parse the resulting diff lines so you can sum up the amounts. (Presumably that's why you're importing `csv`.)

So, if you're going to do that, you can import the values and then, e.g., do a set difference. Or just diff on the fly, something like this (untested, just to show the idea):

```
import csv

with open('file1', 'rb') as f:
  d = {(name, product): amount for name, product, amount in csv.reader(f)}
diff2 = 0.0
with open('file2', 'rb') as f:
  for name, product, amount in csv.reader(f):
  if d.get((name, product)) == amount:
    del d[(name, product)]
  else:
    diff2 += float(amount)
diff1 = sum(float(amount) for amount in d.itervalues())
print diff1 - diff2
```

Comment: @HansThen: His original code doesn't show the part that does any of the actual work of iterating the output of ndiff, parsing it with csv, and converting strings to numbers, summing things up, etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was comparing the proverbial different fruits.